# Can't use window.external.notify() after UglifyJS compressed

Tags: javascript, silverlight, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

recently I've used UglifyJS to compress my js codes for testing. Then I found that after compression, I can't use `window.external.notify()` to notify the WebBrowser control outside. My demo codes are here:

```
function MyNotify () {
    try{
        alert("Notify");
        window.external.notify("Notify");
    } catch (e){
        alert(e.message);
    }
}

function MyNotifyCompressed(){
    try {
        alert("Notify"), window.external.notify("Notify");
    } catch (e) {
        alert(e.message);
    }
}
```

Then I call `WebBrowser.InvokeScript("MyNotifyCompressed")`, it alerts me something like this:

> Object doesn't support this action

Why can't I call the `window.external.notify()` method after compression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We got the same issue. Appears to be a parsing bug in IE on Windows Phone. The problem is that UglifyJS by default replaces semi-colon with commas which causes the strange bug.

Disabling the sequences options solved it for us. From the docs

> sequences     : true,  // join consecutive statemets with the “comma operator

Setting that option to false will make IE happy.

If you use Grunt, add this to the uglify options:

```
compress: {
    sequences: false
}
```